# How to escape attribute for Javascript Template String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, xss

The snippet is

```
function addTabItems(tab, items) {
        const tabItems = items.map((item) => `
                <div class="bvb-cmp-grid__item">
                    <div class="bvb-comp-grid__item-head">
                        <img alt="grid-item" src="${item['image']}" class="bvb-cmp-grid__item-img">
                        <div class="bvb-cmp-grid__item-title">${item['title']}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bvb-comp-grid__item-blocks">
                        ${item['items'].map((block) => `
                                 <div class="bvb-comp-grid__item-block">
                                    <div class="bvb-comp-grid__item-block-title">${block['title']}</div>
                                    <div class="bvb-comp-grid__item-block-content">${block['content']}</div>
                                </div>
                       `).join('')}
                    </div>
                </div>            
            `).join('');
        const $tabContent = $(`[data-bvb-cmp-grid-tab-content="${tab}"]`);

        $tabContent.append(tabItems);
    }
```

Need to achieve - building template by correct way.

How to escape attribue value `src="${item['image']}"` for preventing `XSS` atack?

Comment: How about a) not using strings to build up HTML b) using templating engines that have built in safety? These two are not mutually exclusive, of course.

Comment: @VLAZ, a) Unfourtunately, have no ability to use template engine for the situation I stucked with.

Comment: Then produce the content programatically? a) is not reliant on a templating engine

Comment: @VLAZ, I meant b). The a) could be applied, thanks for advice